# No visual, no beep

Tags: windows-7, cpu

So Win7 just updated and attempted to restart the PC but I received no visual and no beeping sound. I started to unplug all unnecessary hardware components so now all that's left is my boot hd. And yet not even the CPU fan is running.

Answer (score 1):

No fans, no startup of any kind .. sounds like a bad Power Supply Unit.

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo the previous answer of bad PSU but also throw in potential mobo issues.  Swap the PSU first and see what happens.  If it's still a no-go then your motherboard may have taken a dive on you.